# How to write to an ssd in C?

Tags: operating-system, driver

I'm trying to create an operating system, and I'm currently trying to work out basic drivers. On working on storage, I can't find any information pertaining to the ssd and the ports and information I need to access.

I have tried searching for my specific ssd's service manual - the Samsung BJTD4R 32GB eMMC, but all I got was a user manual for a different model

Comment: I would expect it to be mostly a function of the device interface type (SATA? PCIe?), not of the specific device.

Comment: Why are people voting to close? It seems a pretty well defined question to me.

Comment: The seems to be also known by another part number. Have you tried googling for `KLMBG2JETD-B041 datasheet`. The datasheet seems to have pretty comprehensive programming instuctions, though it looks to have a standard HS200/400 interface.

Comment: That seems to have exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: Have you checked [the OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page)? It might have more generic information.

Comment: It's worth adding you should write a driver for devices that share a protocol like IDE, SATA USB, etc. Then each device may or may not need additional configuration to control unique features or fine tuning. This can often be read generically from the device itself.